# In firebase,I've setup a custom domain and it is working.But while FB or Google Authentication in application,the custom domain doesn't working

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I've connected to a custom domain in firebase project. And my web application is hosted and wrking in that custom domain. But in my web app I'm using Firebase sign-in method for Facebook and Google. So when I click login Google box comes up. In that my custom domain is not shown. instead the firebaseapp with my projectid.com is shown. how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Did you replace `authDomain` in your initialization code to use the custom domain?

You need to do that: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#customizing-the-redirect-domain-for-google-sign-in

Answer (score 0):

See [Authenticate Using Facebook Login with JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login?authuser=0) documentation. Try and add your custom domain in there too.

> make sure your OAuth redirect URI (e.g.
>   my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your
>   OAuth redirect URIs in your [Facebook app's settings
>   page](https://developers.facebook.com/) on the Facebook for Developers
>   site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [Customizing the redirect domain for Facebook sign-in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login?authuser=0#expandable-4) which explain the basic steps you have to do.

I want to highlight point 3, as it's the hard part, because it has almost no details. You need to go to `GCP Console > Select project > API Manager > Credentials > Add your my.domain/__/auth/handler link in #2 to the 'Authorized redirect URIs'`